# Optimising Over a Parameter in an Integral

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, optimization

Here is my task:

> Maximise over $a>0$ the following function:
>   $$ f(a) = a e^{-a\sqrt{2r}} \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-{1 \over 2}x^2 - {{\lambda (a - S_0)^2} \over {\sigma^2}} {1 \over x^2} \right)dx $$
>   where $\lambda,\sigma,S_0 > 0$ are constants.

Any advice as to how I can maximise this would be most appreciated! Given that the integral has a reasonably nice form, should be easy: differentiate and set to zero; so my question is really about evaluating the integral.

I thought about a substitution in the integral to get rid of the factor $a$ out the front,
$$y = xa \Rightarrow {{dy}\over{dx}} = a, {{dx}\over{dy}} = 1/a$$ and no change to limits), but this then makes the integrand most complicated...

For background, I have included at the bottom the original question so that those who are interested can see where this integral has come from along with (a scan of) my workings... also, perhaps someone will notice that I've done something wrong! That said, I'm pretty sure what I've done is right: I've done it twice and got the same answer (first time I forgot to use the above parameters so had a special case). *Please note: while this question is from the course "Stochastic Financial Models", this is a* maths *question, not a* finance *question.*

[image: Original Question]

[image: Workings]

If you got this far, thanks! =D

Comment: The integral is doable, then its easy.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. The $1/x^2$ factor made me think that I couldn't just 'Gaussian it'... I'll give it a shot shortly. As you said, yeah, once you've got the integral, then it's pretty easy (I assume!). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user121049 has commented, the integral can indeed be evaluated. It is a Gaussian integral, and (taking a short cut, using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7Dexp%28-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7Dx%5E2-%5Cfrac%7Bk%7D%7Bx%5E2%7D%29dx)) evaluates to
$$f(a)=a\exp(-a\sqrt{2r})\color{blue}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\exp(-\sqrt{2\lambda}\frac{a-S_0}{\sigma})}$$
Maximisation with respect to $a$ can be further simplified by considering $\ln f(a)$, which is
$$\ln f(a)=\ln a+\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{\pi}{2}-\left(\sqrt{2r}+\frac{\sqrt{2\lambda}}{\sigma}\right)a+\frac{\sqrt{2\lambda S_0}}{\sigma}$$
Differentiating this w.r.t. $a$, setting the differential to $0$, and solving for $a$,  yields the following:-
$$\frac{d\ln f(a)}{da}=\frac{1}{a}-\left(\sqrt{2r}+\frac{\sqrt{2\lambda}}{\sigma}\right)=0\Rightarrow a=\frac{\sigma}{\sigma\sqrt{2r}+\sqrt{2\lambda}}$$

Although Wolfram Alpha was used to evaluate the Gaussian integral, it can be done by  using a few substitutions, which I will detail below.

Suppose we wish to evaluate 
$$I=\int_0^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{k}{x^2}\right)\ dx \text{ (1)}$$
Using substitution  $y=\frac{\sqrt{2k}}{x}$, the integral will become
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}y^2-\frac{k}{y^2}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{2k}}{y^2}\right)\ dy \text{ (2)}$$
Applying a direct substitution $x = y$ on Equation $(2)$ leads to
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{k}{
x^2}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{2k}}{x^2}\right)\ dx \text{ (3)}$$
Adding Equations $(1)$ and $(3)$ results in
$$2I=\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{k}{
x^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{2k}}{x^2}\right)\ dx \text{ (4)}$$
Applying a final substitution $z=x-\frac{\sqrt{2k}}{x}$ to Equation $(4)$ will lead to the standard form of the Gaussian integral with limits $-\infty$ to $\infty$, and a multiplicative constant arising from completing the square. This final evaluation is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I can obviously see the relation to the Gaussian integral, but my issue was this: you get a factor $(x + 1/x)^2$ (up to constants), then if you substitute this, say $y = x + 1/x$, then $dy/dx = -1/x^2$, which I can't see how you'd get rid of...

Comment: Given your first formula, I can easily maximise it (either taking the log, or just directly), but I can't see how to evaluate it... :/

Comment: I've given it a go, but can't get anywhere... If you could give advice for a substitution or whatever (not a full answer), then that'd be great. :)

Comment: @SmileySam: Please see edits to my answer - as per your comment, I haven't given the full answer.

Comment: Ah, clever! I'd got down to a setup similar to $(4)$, then applying the $z$ transformation at the end, but I have the final term "${}^{-1}$". Obviously, having your term there cancels beautifully.

Comment: What I hadn't thought of doing was the first substitution, but I should have since you have the term $(x + {\sqrt{2k} \over x})$ which obviously is unchanged under $y = {\sqrt{2k} \over x}$.

Comment: If I'm honest, I don't see the need for the difference between $(2)$ and $(3)$ - was this just so that it's more obvious when adding together? Of course, just a dummy variable so you could just change $y$ to a picture of a small owl and wouldn't make any difference! =P

Comment: Yes you're right - there wasn't really a need for the difference between (2) and (3) - it was just to make the addition more obvious - a small owl would have been just as good!

Comment: I don't think MathJax has that in it's formatting though... at least, not as easily available as '$x$' or '$y$'!